# webscraping on websocket streaming using Python 3.x

Tags: python, web-scraping, websocket

I've been webscraping for a long time and recently decided to scrape a video stream via websocket streaming. I fully understand websockets and how they work, but I don't fully understand the streaming part.
I'm trying to scrape a stream where I get base64 data using Python 3.10, and when I try to decode it I find that it can't be read (exactly because it's data from the video stream).
The stream I'm trying to extract is from a company that provides some weather data and I need to get that data without needing to use Selenium or some other library for testing.
Is there any effective way to do this? Maybe some well performing library, or some way to "read" the data from the stream somehow?

Here is an impression that I took from the data obtained by the websocket:
[image]

Even after trying to decode the obtained base64 to utf-8, the result is the same as the image above.

Answer (score 8):

I can recommend this package: https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client

It is pretty simple and stable and it works flawlessly. Also it supports asyncio.

```
def on_message(ws, message):
    ...

def on_open(ws):
    ...

def on_close(ws, close_status_code, close_msg):
    ...

def on_error(ws, error):
    ...

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(
    "wss://<address>",
    on_open=on_open,
    on_message=on_message,
    on_error=on_error,
    on_close=on_close,
)
ws.run_forever()
```

Usually when scraping WS you need to initiate the proccess by sending some command (you can track it by Dev Tools also, this package will be marked as green up arrow). Then you can reproduce it by using `ws.send("<message>")`

Comment: can you read and write the whole video and watch it on your desktop using this technique?

Comment: I assume It highly depends on the format and the codec of your video. Have you checked if it was h264 as the obvious solution?

Comment: First of all you can try to catch these messages out of WS, write them down to file and then try to read it

Comment: I already tried to do exactly that with this library, as I mentioned, I already understand about websocket and I already have some working projects, but the difference is that they all receive and send utf-8 data, but in this case I receive base64 data, which even trying decode do not result in anything.

Comment: Can you please upload few chunks of raw data, received by python or tell me the endpoint if is open? I'll try to test it

Comment: sure, I will send a base64 example of something similar:

`gABuEgADAAFwEgACAAFwEgADAA1jdXJyZW50UGF5b3V0Bz/964UeuFHsAARjb2RlBAAAAMgAD2N1cnJlbnRHYW1lVGltZQUAAAAAAAAdsAABYwgAEWN1cnJlbnRNdWx0aXBsaWVyAAFhAwANAAFjAgE=`

Comment: It looks like a json-like datastructure (because we see some keywords when trying to perform base64 decode). It can be encrypted by zlib or something similar. Maybe you can provide any other message related to video stream?